# lpr with reverse video

Tags: printing, lpr

When sending a text file to the printer from the command line (by, e.g., `lpr -P printer-name file.txt`), is it possible to specify that inverted colors be used by the printer (i.e., white text on black background)?

Answer (score 0):

`lpr` does not have an option for this.  Your printer *may* accept an option that can be used for this purpose.  To use that hypothetical option, you would use `lpoptions`:

- use `lpoptions -l` to list the available options, and
- use `lpoptions -o` to set a particular option.

These are CUPS commands, and likely are on your computer.

Different printers have different options.

Further reading:

- [**`lpoptions`** - display or set printer options and defaults](https://www.cups.org/doc/man-lpoptions.html)
- [**`lpr`** - print files](https://www.cups.org/doc/man-lpr.html?TOPIC=Man%20Pages)
- [Why is the printer reversing black and white?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4411/why-is-the-printer-reversing-black-and-white)